# why does session ID changes often?

Tags: php, database, session, session-cookies, session-storage

I have set sessions storage in database. When I call `session_destroy` , it searches for specific `session_id`  in the database to delete it.

As session id changes often, new session_id doesn't match with db session_id which was stored before, So these sessions data doesn't get deleted. Even gc also not working. All the session data is getting saved into the database but is not destroyed.

**DbSessionHandler.php**

```
class DbSessionHandler implements SessionHandlerInterface{

public $dbconnect;
public function __construct($db){
    $this->dbconnect=$db;
    session_set_save_handler(
        array($this, 'open'),
        array($this, 'close'),
        array($this, 'read'),
        array($this, 'write'),
        array($this, 'destroy'),
        array($this, 'gc')
    );
    register_shutdown_function(session_write_close());
    session_start();
}

//make sure whether db connection is successfull
public function open($savepath, $id)
{
    return $this->dbconnect ? true : false;
}

public function close()
{
    return true;
}

//read from database based on id, always return a string even if it is empty
public function read($id)
{
    $data = "";   //declare empty string, if no data found, can return this empty string
    $session_row = $this->dbconnect->prepare("select session_data from session_store where session_id=:id");
    $session_row->execute(array(":id" => $id));
    if ($session_row->rowCount() > 0) {
        $datas = $session_row->fetch();
        $data=$datas["session_data"];
    }
    return $data;

}

/**
 * Write session_data using replace query (which does either insert or update)
 */
public function write($id, $data)
{
    if(!(empty($data))) {
        $time = time();
        $session_write = $this->dbconnect->prepare("REPLACE INTO session_store VALUES(:id,:data,:expire)");
        if ($session_write->execute(array(":id" => $id, ":data" => $data, ":expire" => $time))) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

/**
 * Destroy
 */
public function destroy($id)
{
    $destroy = $this->dbconnect->prepare("delete from session_store where session_id = :id");
    if ($destroy->execute(array(":id" => $id))) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

/**
 * Garbage Collection
 */
public function gc($max)
{
    //Delete all records who have passed the expiration time
    $time=time();
    $delete = $this->dbconnect->prepare("delete from session_store where session_expire < :oldtime");
    if ($delete->execute(array(":oldtime" => $time - $max))) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

}

**php file which starts the session:**

```
function initiate_session()
{
$session_hash = 'sha512';
$session_name = 'some_name';
$secure = false;
$httponly = true;
ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', 1);
ini_set('session.hash_function', $session_hash);
ini_set('session.hash_bits_per_character', 5);
$cookieParams = session_get_cookie_params();
session_set_cookie_params($cookieParams['lifetime'], $cookieParams['path'], $cookieParams['domain'], $secure, $httponly);
session_name($session_name);
new DbSessionHandler(db_connect());
```

}

[image: session_id]

In the this image you can see that, session_id in the table and session_id in the script are different that makes session data in the database not to get deleted.

Comment: Is session_id changing for logged users or for new users?

Comment: Logged users. Sometimes  some  session records  are getting  deleted  as there would  be no session id change.  Sometimes  it doesn't  get deleted  because  of different  session id for the same user.  So the thing  is,  not always  session id changes.

Answer (score -1):

try to use this 
session_regenerate_id(true);

passing TRUE boolean value will destroy the old session id while create another.
u can add this to the initiate_session() function.